# Weird and unexpected results from a simple series

Tags: javascript, math, series

With a simple JS code I calculate the sum of the following series:

[image: Series]

`b` is a constant, could be any value. 
The JS code tries to find for which **minimum** value `r` (given it *1000 attempts* in this example), this inequality is valid:

[image: Series 2]

If `r` goes below `1.50000`, results get silly.

```
var pre = 0.0;
var r = 1.50010;
var b = 0.01;

for (var p = 0; p < 1000; p++) {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= 33; i++) {
      sum += Math.pow(r, i);
   }

   sum *= b;

   if ((2 * b * Math.pow(r, 34)) > sum) {
      pre = r;
      r -= 0.00001;
      r = parseFloat(r.toFixed(5));
   } else {
      console.log(pre);
      console.log(((2 * b * Math.pow(r + 0.00001, 34)) - sum).toFixed(8));
      break;
   }
}
```

The code breaks at `pre == 1.5`, and if I were to force `r = 1.49999`, `console.log(pre)` returns `0`. Why?

Comment: The `k + 1` in the left-hand side is wrong.  There is no `k` as far as I can tell.  On the right, `k` is simply a bound variable of iteration.  `k + 1` should just be `34`, right?

Comment: My bad, yes, the `33` value is supposed to change. Why is there no `k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code stops when r = 1.5 because that's the minimum value for which your inequality is valid (within the accuracy you're using, anyway). If you start r off at less than that, it's going to break on the first time through the loop since that if statement is never true, so you never set pre to be r.

Here's a graph showing what happens with the two sides of the inequality near r = 1.5: [image: Plot of 2 * r^34 and sum of r^i from i = 0 to 33]

Code for the above graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(1.4, 1.6, 100)
plt.plot(x , 2 * x ** 34, label = '$2r^{34}$')
plt.plot(x , sum([x ** i for i in xrange(34)]), label = '$\sum_{i = 0}^{33}\/ r^i$')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Also, if b is positive, you don't need to do anything with b in your code, since you're multiplying both sides of the inequality by b. And if b is negative, then you need to reverse the inequality.

Oh, and another thing: for algorithms of this type, you may want to consider something more like the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), which halves the search space each time through the iteration. You could use 1 and 2 as the endpoints, since 1 is definitely too low and 2 is definitely too high. You'd stop when the difference between the sides of the inequality fell below some threshold.

Comment: Why is it the minimum value for which the inequality is valid?

Comment: @ShinyPhoenix, I added a graph; does that help?

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you!

Comment: Amy Teegarden, may I ask you how did you graph those two functions?

Comment: I used a python package called matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/). I put the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that when the loop breaks, you want to display the difference between the left and right of the inequality.  The problem is because "sum" is a running sum that is from the previous loop, the calculation is not correct.

Now when you force r = 1.49999, the if clause is never executed so "pre" stays at zero as initiated on the first line.

Your full solution should be like this:

```
var pre = 0.0;
var r = 1.50010;
var b = 0.01;

for (var p = 0; p < 1000; p++) {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= 33; i++) {
      sum += Math.pow(r, i);
   }

   sum *= b;

   var diff = (2 * b * Math.pow(r, 34) - sum).toFixed(8);
   console.log('diff: ' + diff);
   if ((2 * b * Math.pow(r, 34)) > sum) {
      pre = r;
      r -= 0.00001;
      r = parseFloat(r.toFixed(5));
   } else {
      console.log('--breaking--');
      console.log(pre);
      //console.log(((2 * b * Math.pow(r + 0.00001, 34)) - sum).toFixed(8));
      break;
   }
}
```

and the output is:

```
diff: 3.91098781
diff: 3.52116542
diff: 3.13150396
diff: 2.74200338
diff: 2.35266364
diff: 1.96348468
diff: 1.57446646
diff: 1.18560893
diff: 0.79691205
diff: 0.40837575
diff: 0.02000000
diff: -0.36821526
--breaking--
1.5
```

Comment: Oh, that's why! Thank you!